# Loading data from one table into two other tables (one detail, one summary) that are related

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose that I have a source table like this:

```
Source
    SourceKey (PK)
    Data1
    Data2
    Amount
```

And I am loading data from 'Source' into two related tables that look like this:

```
Summary
    SummaryKey (PK)
    Data1
    Data2
    Amount

Detail
    DetailKey (PK)
    SummaryKey (FK)
    SourceKey (FK)
    Data2
    Amount
```

**EDIT**

Ignoring the problem of relating 'Summary' and 'Detail', the ideal insert statements would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Summary (Data1, Data2, Amount)
SELECT Data1, Data2, SUM(Amount) FROM Source GROUP BY Data1, Data2

INSERT INTO Detail (SummaryKey, SourceKey, Data2, Amount)
SELECT ???, SourceKey, Data2, Amount FROM Source
```

I've 'solved' this problem with a pair of temporary holding tables (corresponding to the destination tables) along with a semi-complicated UPDATE statement to relate them by matching on grouping fields (the *real* example has a much more complicated grouping). I can't help but feel there exists a simpler solution than what I've created.

Any solution would need to work under SQL Server 2000. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server, and what kind of data is in Data1 and Data2?

Comment: Also, what's the basis of the aggregation? There's no obvious link between either SummaryKey in the Summary/Detail tables and any field in the Source table.

Answer (score 2):

Since your design leaves much to be desired but is unchangeable. I thinkthe best approach is to use a cursor (boy I hate to suggest this).

Pull the source into a staging table that has an additional column of SummaryKey which will remain blank and an identity key called StagingKey.
Using a cursor, insert the records one at a time into summary. After each insert pull the value of of scope_identity() and update the record with the staging key that you just inserted to put this value into the staging table.
Once all are done, you should have all you need to insert to the detail table in one insert rather than a cursor.

In newer versions of SQL Server, you could use the output clause and use a set-based insert for the first table too.

Comment: I've given you an up-vote for an answer that would work given the constraints I've imposed. Like you, I have a strong aversion to any solution involving cursors, so I'll stick with my 'complicated' solution for now. Thanks anyways.

Comment: If you have to do this often with large tables, it's a good reason to upgrade to 2008 where the output clause makes it a much simpler task.

Answer (score 0):

Use `triggers` to create the row, when an insert is done on your summary table, in the second table. It will let you to fix the foreign keys by one shot.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a think about how to solve this with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or `@@IDENTITY`, without triggers where possible, but then it struck me - where is the necessity of the `Summary` table at all?

Could it not be replaced by a view, which in the example would be along the lines of `SELECT Data1, Data2, SUM(amount) FROM Detail GROUP BY Data1, Data2` ? 
(Obviously in your exact example the detail table doesn't have the Data1 field, but I've used poetic license for that!)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, in the real example, the schema of the source and destination tables is fixed. Besides that, there are other reasons why an indexed view is not feasible.

Comment: ANd don;t use @@idnetity for this. It will give the wrong answer if anyone ever adds a trigger that does an insert to a table with an identity. Use of @@identity is a data integrity nightmare waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of doing this? If you're just doing it for performance reasons it seems like this might be a good candidate for an indexed view.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please see my reply to doogstar.